# wxControl or wxWindow when making custom widgets using wxWidgets

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I would like to ask between these two classes which would be appropriate to use when making custom widgets eg. custom buttons. I am still new to wxWidgets but i can not seem to find proper resources on the framework. The official documentation is really useful to understand event propagation, data types, functions etc. I just want a brief explanation of the best use cases for wxControl and wxWindow

I tried using wxWindow to make a custom button but i was having issues setting a custom background. The constructor also seems different from that of wxControl

Comment: I believe that wxControl is intended to be used when providing a wxWidgets wrapper for a native control such as a button or a checkbox.  Without seeing code, I can only offer a general suggestion for the background issue. For a custom background, it's probably best to set wxBG_STYLE_PAINT for the background style and be sure to redraw the entire window in its paint handle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either class, there is not much difference between them when creating a new generic window.

When wrapping a new native control, `wxControl` should be used, and it could also be useful to derive from it if your control using mnemonics, markup or "ellipsization", as this class has some helper functions for all of those.

Comment: I find that when i use wxControl, the PaintEvent gets cropped out a bit so i went with wxWIndow for the project i was working on

Comment: There really shouldn't be any difference in paint events handling between the two.